# Running google_sql I get invalid syntax error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-3.x

Running:

- Google Cloud SDK 0.9.9
- Python 3.3

When I execute the below:

```
c:\google-cloud-sdk-0.9.9\bin>google_sql reaperfire-cloud-sql
```

I get the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\google-cloud-sdk-0.9.9\bin\gauth", line 10, in <module>
    import bootstrapping.bootstrapping as bootstrapping
  File "c:\google-cloud-sdk-0.9.9\bin\bootstrapping\bootstrapping.py", line 251
    print 'There are currently no authorized credentials.',
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google_sql requires Python 2, and not 3...downloading python 2.x worked. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In python 3 `print` is a function so you have to write it like this:

```
print("Hello, World!")
```

in 2 its like this:

```
print 'Hello, World!'
```

look here for more on [Printing in Python 3](http://www.harshj.com/2008/12/09/the-new-print-function-in-python-3/)